# In android Studio my app shows this error when i sync now

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, jitsi

Gradle Sync Failed:

> Error: Could not set unknown property 'transitive' for object of type
> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

what is the solution for this error..

Comment: You should add more details.